# Radio buttons change CSS background-color or background-image (simple code without labels)

Tags: html, css, radio-button

Is there a way to only by using css change the appearance of radio buttons. But, simple input radio, not with the labels css adjustment.

Like, here is my code: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Rh9ns/)

```
<input type="radio" name="radio1" class="radiostyle" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="radio1" class="radiostyle" value="2">
<input type="radio" name="radio1" class="radiostyle" value="3">
```

Then, here is my css:

```
input[type=radio] {  
    display: none;  
}  

.radiostyle {
    display:inline-block;
    width:19px;
    height:19px;
    background-color: blue;
    /*or instead of color use some image*/
}
```

Therefore, is there I way how to easy do it. Because, I would like to put images instead of simple radio buttons.

Comment: Not much, if anything, you can do to a single element (even using :before or :after) once you set the display to none.

Comment: What is wrong with using `<label>`s? That's pretty much the only way to do it using just CSS

Answer (score 1):

With the experimental `pointer-events` property, it is possible. Although, I highly recommend the (proper) use of labels to increase accessibility for your website. Labels would also allow for a wider range of browser compatibility. Also, since it's an experimental property, I'm not sure of its future existence or support.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SombreErmine/KSD36/8/)

[List of support for `pointer-events`](http://caniuse.com/#search=css%20pointer-events)

**CSS Code:**

```
input[type=radio]:before {
    display: block;
    width: 19px;
    height: 19px;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/19/19);
    pointer-events: none;
}

input[type=radio]:checked:before {
    background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/25/25);
}

.radiostyle {
    display:inline-block;
    width:19px;
    height:19px;
    background-color: blue;
    /*or instead of color use some image*/
}
```

Comment: Did it work for you? I thought there's no way to use `before` or `after` on non-containers — see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587669/can-i-use-the-after-pseudo-element-on-an-input-field).

Comment: Yep. The JSFiddle seemed to not work because the website I was using for the images seems to be broken. I've updated the JSFiddle with an alternative placeholder image website.